# Ruby/Rails .first .last .current?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there such a thing as .current in Ruby/Rails?

I have the following in my Release model to accept tracks as nested attributes. I'm using :after_add to manually set the position column in the has_many through join table. I ideally want this to be populated from either the position attribute sent from the fields_for part of my form or copied from the value set in the tracks table/model on save.

I can get it to set the first or last positions on all entries, but not the current position that relates to that track?

I ideally need **releases_tracks.each { |t| t.position = self.tracks.last.position }** to be something like **releases_tracks.each { |t| t.position = self.tracks.current.position }**

```
has_many :releases_tracks, :dependent => :destroy, :after_add => :position_track
has_many :tracks, :through => :releases_tracks, :order => "position"

accepts_nested_attributes_for :tracks, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => :true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :releases_tracks

def position_track(track) 
  releases_tracks.each { |t| t.position = self.tracks.last.position }
end
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say for sure if I understood you correctly, but, as far as I can tell, `releases_tracks.each { |t| t.position = t.track.position }` should solve your problem.

`belongs_to` - `has_many` relationship works two ways, so for two models «Owner» and «Belonging» bound by such relationship both `Owner.first.belonging` and `Belonging.last.owner` queries are valid.

Comment: Hurrah! That works, thank you. Seems simple now you've pointed it out but I had been through loads of different permutations on this.